# How are the terminal voltages regulated for this Wheatstone bridge?

Tags: wheatstone-bridge

At page 34 from [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/24301f.pdf) datasheet the following circuit shows a single-ended amplifier used to produce single-ended gain:

[image]

As you see the excitation voltage terminals is sensed by Kelvin connection method as REF+ and REF-.

By why are these terminals sensed in this case? Normally they should be sensed to regulate the excitation voltage but in this case I cannot see any feedback circuit. Are the REF+ and REF- signals really used to regulate the excitation terminals voltages in this circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Voltage applied to the Wheatstone bridge comes from VCC and GND, it is not precisely controlled.

As the voltage is applied, a current will flow through the bridge and you will have parasitic impedance down the lines.

5V at the chip might not be 5V at the bridge, but perhaps 4.98V due to parasitic impedance.

The chip sense the voltage at the Wheatstone bridge to sense the true voltage at the bridge, without the parasitic impedance and then compensate the measurement accordingly.

This method is called kelvin or 4-points measurement.

Comment: I see so it is not regulated? How is it compensated? I mean what happens if the voltage sensed is 4.95V instead of 5V. In guess there is no regulation if I understand you but what does the LTC chip do as process in that case?

Comment: Exact, it is not regulated, it is sensed. Then that's the chip and manufacturer magic sauce and IP to compensate, you don't need to care about it, the datasheet will give you the accuracy of the whole system.

Comment: No - this is isn't correct. There's no compensation/magic sauce, it's just a normal ADC but with the references tied to the excitation voltage so you don't have to worry about a precise reference. Making a high precision *and* low impedance excitation source is hard.

Comment: One last question. At page 38 there is another topology. In that one are the excitation voltages at terminals regulated?: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/24301f.pdf At page 38 Figure 45

Comment: Yes, there is a 5V reference, and a opamp as feedback regulator that adjust the voltage to the wheatstone bridge. This seems to be a topology where you need a higher voltage on the wheatstone bridge than the VCC max of the chip. The four RN1 will introduce a temperature drift to the system on this topology.

Answer (score 1):

Using the bridge excitation voltage as the ADC reference gets around the problem of requiring a high precision and also low impedance excitation voltage source. The Wheatstone bridge is sensed differentially, so as long as the ADC reference tracks the excitation it doesn't matter what the exact excitation voltage is. The Kelvin connection is used so that the reference voltages are exactly the same as the excitation voltage seen at the bridge.

To expand on this, consider the circuit you've given. The differential output from the Wheatstone bridge is given by:

\$V_G = (\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} - \frac{R_x}{R_x + R_3})\cdot V_S\$

To simplify this, let's assume that \$V_- = 0\ \mathrm{V}\$ and take all the resistance terms into \$A\$, which gives:

\$V_o = A\cdot V_+\$

The important part here is that the output voltage from the bridge is dependent on the excitation voltage, \$V_+\$. This implies that you need to regulate this voltage to get consistent results. It is worth noting that the impedance of the Wheatstone bridge may be quite low, so you need a high accuracy low impedance voltage source. Most accurate and precise voltage sources generally don't supply high currents, so this presents a potentially expensive design problem.

However, the way this circuit is designed avoids this problem. Again assuming the negative input is at ground, the output from the ADC is given by:

\$D_N = \frac{V_\mathrm{IN+}}{V_\mathrm{REF+}}\cdot 2^N\$

where \$N\$ is the resolution of the ADC in number of bits. The output code depends on the reference voltage \$V_\mathrm{REF+}\$. Now, let's digitise the output from the Wheatstone bridge:

\$D_N = \frac{A\cdot V_+}{V_\mathrm{REF+}}\cdot 2^N\$

It's easy to see from this that if \$V_+ = V_\mathrm{REF+}\$ then the output code becomes independent of the excitation voltage and ADC reference voltage, so it is not necessary to provide the highest quality fixed sources:

\$D_N = A\cdot 2^N\$

This also means the output from the Wheatstone bridge does not exceed the ADC reference voltage. The Kelvin connection ensures that the excitation and ADC reference voltage are the same, so this cancellation works.